# PHP wpdb get_var query returning zero

Tags: php, json, api, wordpress

I have the following code, which is adding some data to a database via server side API. The field order_number should be created via $OrderNumberNext, which is calculated by a count(*)+1 as order_num variable.

However, checking the database after this is done shows that this only ever calculates as 0 (zero). Should I be using a different function call for this?

```
 function addChartToSet($chartId, $setId){
     $chartWithId = $this->db->get_var($this->db->prepare("select id from chords where chord_id=%s",$chartId));
     $setWithId = $this->db->get_var($this->db->prepare("select id from sets where set_id=%s",$setId));     

     $orderNumberNext = $this->db->get_var($this->db->prepare("select count(*)+1 as `order_num` from `chords_inside_sets` where `set_id`=%s",$setId));

     $this->db->query($this->db->prepare("update sets set `last_updated_time`=NOW() where `set_id`=%s",$setId));
     $this->db->query($this->db->prepare("insert into `chords_inside_sets` set `chord_id`=%s , `set_id`=%s, `order_number`= %s",$chartWithId,$setWithId,$orderNumberNext));

     return array("last_updated_time"=>  $this->getMaxUpdatedTimeForSet($setId), "query"=>  $this->db->last_query);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding 1 inside the query that fetches the data. It cannot work. Get your count first through the SELECT query, then add one on the next line, like this:

```
 $orderNumberNext = $this->db->get_var($this->db->prepare("select count(*) as `order_num` from `chords_inside_sets` where `set_id`=%s",$setId));
$orderNumberNext++;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I have tried this, but it is still not working. It was returning 0 before, now it is returning 1 (after the ++).

Comment: Also, I tried to change this to get_row, and then pull the order_num from the variable ($orderNumberNext->order_num.  This also does not produce what I need.

Comment: Any thoughts here? Could it be a setting in PHP that is causing the problem? The query works fine in Sequel PRO, but doesn't work when running it from code.